# Lifetime of C++ class members

Tags: c++, raii

What is the lifetime of a C++ class member. For example, at which time will the `std::fstream` of a `Foo` object be released? When entering the destructor or when leaving the destructor? Is this defined in the C++ standard?

```
struct Foo
{
    std::fstream mystream;
    ~Foo()
    {
        // wait for thread writing to mystream
    }
};
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `mystream` data member is destroyed during the destruction of the `Foo` object, *after* the body of `~Foo()` is executed.  C++11 §12.4[class.dtor]/8 states:

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class `X` calls the destructors for `X`'s direct non-variant non-static data members, the destructors for `X`'s direct base classes and, if `X` is the type of the most derived class, its destructor calls the destructors for `X`'s virtual base classes.

`mystream` is a non-variant, non-static data member of `Foo` (a *variant* data member is a member of a union; `Foo` is not a union).

Answer (score 3):

It's the reverse of construction:

> construction: base classes, data members (`mystream` constructed here), constructor body
>
> destruction: destructor body, data members (`mystream` destroyed here), base classes

Comment: what if class member is a pointer to one local member? `string *name` , then name is the pointer that declared in one method, out of method name will be destroyed then how about the class's `*name` ?

Comment: @TomSawyer: Doesn't matter what it points at. The pointer itself is still a data member.

Comment: I know, but it it will become dangling pointer, since the memory address it pointed to has been deallocated after out of scope.